# c# Can I do this for "if"? or any other way to doing something like this?

Tags: c#

```
if ((((a > 0) && ((b > 0) || (c> 0) || (d> 0) || (e> 0))) ||
((a1 > 0) && ((b> 0) || (c > 0) || (d > 0) || (e> 0))) ||
((a2 > 0) && ((b> 0) || (c> 0) || (d> 0) || (e> 0))) ||
((a3> 0) && ((b> 0) || c> 0) || (d> 0) || (e> 0)))) && 
((75.5 > d1 && d1 > 74.5) || (75.5 > d2 && d2 > 74.5)))
{
    //do something
}
```

just want to make the condition of the IF as the following:

(a > 0 and( b > 0 or c > 0 or d > 0 or e > 0)) and ((d1< 75.5 and d1>74.5 ) or (d2<75.5 and d2>74.5))
or
(a1 > 0 and( b > 0 or c > 0 or d > 0 or e > 0)) and ((d1< 75.5 and d1>74.5 ) or (d2<75.5 and d2>74.5))
or
(a2 > 0 and( b > 0 or c > 0 or d > 0 or e > 0)) and ((d1< 75.5 and d1>74.5 ) or (d2<75.5 and d2>74.5))
or
(a3 > 0 and( b > 0 or c > 0 or d > 0 or e > 0)) and ((d1< 75.5 and d1>74.5 ) or (d2<75.5 and d2>74.5))

for the same conditions for a1 to a3

cos I have created a for loop before these code to do some checking , and those a,a1,a2,a3,b,c,d,e are the ints which have added 1 under some special condition in the for loop, and i just want to do some further grouping in this if() and just wonder if this multi "Ands" and "Ors" will work or not

Comment: Can you try to edit this in the form of a question?  It's a bit unclear what you're looking for.  Thanks.

Comment: This is an English-only site. "sth" is not English.

Comment: I guess English is for n00bs...

Comment: Please put enough effort into your question to actually use words, and to explain what you're actually trying to do. It seems to me that for maintenance purposes, you'd want to separate that out into logical steps instead of making one single hard to read `if` to start with, though. (If you sent that code to me as a sample with a job app, I wouldn't schedule an interview. :) )

Comment: thx for ur comments will improve my next question, just want to learn more basicly,still noob at both english and C#

Answer (score 3):

I would break this out into more booleans to simplify it

```
bool biggerZero = (b > 0) || (c> 0) || (d> 0) || (e> 0));
bool anAzero = a > 0 || a1 > 0 || a2 > 0 || a3 > 0;
bool d1range = 75.5 > d1 && d1 > 74.5;
bool d2range = 75.5 > d2 && d2 > 74.5;
bool solution = anAzero && biggerZero && (d1range || d2range);
```

Answer (score 1):

Generally it is much clearer to place the common subexpressions in separate variables when they are repeated in a complex expression. That should make no difference to the compiler in terms of optimization.

Your parenthesis are not balanced so I'm not 100% sure what your code is expressing, but for example you could declare

```
bool aThroughEGreaterEqualZero = (b > 0) || (c> 0) || (d> 0) || (e> 0);
```

and use that in place of all occurrences of that evaluation in your `if`.

For the sake of the next person to maintain the code, I would break down the expression in the `if` statement into a number of meaningfully-named variables, and then use those variables in the actual `if`.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a helper method for checking the repetitive code like:

```
Func<bool> conditionExpression => (int a, int b, int c, int d, int e) =>
{
    return a > 0 && (b | c |d | e) > 0;
}
bool dWithinRange = (d1 < 75.5 && d1 > 74.5 ) || (d2 < 75.5 and d2 > 74.5);

if (conditionExpression(a, b, c, d, e) &&
    conditionExpression(a1, b1, c1, d1, e1) &&
    conditionExpression(a2, b2, c2, d2, e2) &&
    conditionExpression(a3, b3, c3, d3, e3) &&
    dWithinRange
{
    // finally
}
```

I queess however that the most helpfull modification would be for giving your variables understandable names. It's unlikely that a reader of your code will understand what d1 is and why it has to be smaller than ...